# R - generate multiple datasets for vioplot based on number of levels of a column

Tags: r, violin-plot

When I am using violin plot for one species (Pan), my code looks like this:

```
my.vioplot(getFemales(toPlotAggregated,"Pan"),getMales(toPlotAggregated,"Pan"),col=c("red","blue"),names=c("females","males"))
```

it generates single plot with females in red and males in blue. However, I would like to iterate through all species I have which is what is in this variable:

```
levels(factor(toPlotAggregated$species))
```

vioplot accepts arbitrary number of datasets so since I need both females and males for each species, I need to generate 2*(number of species) datasets to pass to vioplot. So for two species it would be something like:

```
my.vioplot(SPECIES1_females,SPECIES1_males,SPECIES2_females,SPECIES2_males,...)
```

I have tried doing this with "by" and "apply" but with no success so far.

EDIT:

Example of my data:

```
dput(tail(toPlotAggregated))
structure(list(name = c("Taweh", "Bwambale", "Vincent", "Bosco", 
"Clint", "Buschi"), species = c("Pan", "Pan", "Pan", "Pan", "Pan", 
"Pongo"), fullSpecies = c("Pan_troglodytes_ellioti", "Pan_troglodytes_schweinfurthii", 
"Pan_troglodytes_schweinfurthii", "Pan_troglodytes_verus", "Pan_troglodytes_verus", 
"Pongo_abelii"), sex = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), counts = c(52.989924558446, 
85.2531017739286, 118.811705035969, 65.8304927403788, 48.0129119517474, 
63.7682831797004)), .Names = c("name", "species", "fullSpecies", 
"sex", "counts"), row.names = 54:59, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you dump some of your data for us to use?  Try `dput(your_data)`

Comment: I just did, thanks. Basically for each species, I need to plot both males and females, all in one plot as arguments of vioplot:)